# Правильно построить логику в each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как правильно построить следующую логику:

Существует множество `.row` строк с вложенными в них `div`. `div`'ов может быть 1, 2, 5 с относительно уникальными атрибутами и т.д. Необходимо скрывать целиком весь `row`, если не один из `div`'ов внутри него не совпадает по условию. Кроме того, внутри `row`, в котором нашлись совпадения, нужно скрыть те `div`'ы, которые не удовлетворили условию.

Когда я использую конструкцию ниже, то все срабатывает хорошо, но ровно до того момента, как в том самом `.row` не окажется более чем 1 `div`. Так получается, что в 1 `div` атрибут не совпадает, а в другом совпадает, но удаляется целиком строка. Как можно решить ?

```
$(".containerItems .row div[data-game]:not([data-search*='" + symbol + "'])").each(function(){

    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");                       
});
```

Если же убрать `parent()`

```
$(".containerItems .row div[data-game]:not([data-search*='" + symbol + "'])").each(function(){

    $(this).fadeOut("fast");                        
});
```

то остаются пробелы тех самых `.row`. Ведь `display none` применяется ко вложенному `div`, который соответствует условиям.

Примерный вид div

```
<div data-game="cs go" data-search="cs go go cs контра кс кс го го коэс" class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main">
<div class="promo-game-item">
<div class="game-title"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а так: `$(this).fadeOut('fast', ()=>{$(this).hide();});`

Comment: +может хотя бы из консоли разработчика пару элементов сюда вставишь чтоб нам играться?

Comment: @Vadim добавил структуру `div`'a. Подобные (от 1 до н штук), с различием лишь в `data-search `лежат внутри нескольких `.row` идущих друг за другом. Ваш пример выше не помог, к  сожалению :(

Comment: Тю, я чот перепутал, hide это фейд без анимации) вместо hide -> remove

Comment: а вообще, когда похожим действом занимаешься, можно использовать `.css('background','red');` и менять цвет, смотреть через ф12 у кого цвет меняется

Comment: @Vadim и ремув тоже не делает того, чего хочется (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвета поменяй на `fadeOut`, это для наглядности

```js
const sleep=(ms)=>new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, ms));

(async()=>{
    await sleep(2000);
    const symb = 'cs 1.6';
    $('.containerItems > .row').each((i, e)=>{
        const one = $(e).children(`div[data-search*="${symb}"]`);
        if(one.length > 0){
            one.css('background', 'green');
            $(e).children(`div:not([data-search*="${symb}"])`).css('background', 'red');
        }else{
            $(e).children().css('background','darkred'); // $(e).fadeOut();
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
.game-main{
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.containerItems{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='containerItems'>
  <!-- ONE -->
  row 1
  <div class="row">
    <div data-game='cs go' data-search='cs go go cs' class='col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main'>
      <div class='promo-game-item'>
        <div class='game-title'>
          Title1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-game='asd' data-search='asd' class='col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main'>
      <div class='promo-game-item'>
        <div class='game-title'>
          Title2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-game='zzzz cs' data-search='go go' class='col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main'>
      <div class='promo-game-item'>
        <div class='game-title'>
          Title3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- TWO -->
  row 2
  <div class="row">
    <div data-game='cs 1.6' data-search='cs' class='col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main'>
      <div class='promo-game-item'>
        <div class='game-title'>
          Title4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-game='csze' data-search='cs 1.6' class='col-md-3 col-xs-4 game-main'>
      <div class='promo-game-item'>
        <div class='game-title'>
          Title5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подредактировал у Вас..посмотрите, может понятней будет )) Если Вам правка не видна, скажите, залью на хост какой нибудь

Comment: @steam.apk2 видны

Comment: @steam.apk2 чек

Comment: Уже приблизительно то, что нужно. Спасибо!)
Единственная нерешенная проблема - сейчас введены символы `cs go`, значит, должно показывать `1 div, 3 div` в `row1`  и `1 div + 2 div` в `row2` т.к их атрибуты частично ведь совпадают

Comment: @steam.apk2 они не будут совпадать, ибо валуе в *двойных* кавычках `[data-search*="${symb}"]`

Comment: Увидел ,спасибо! А можно ли как то обратиться к предыдущему `div`, если вдруг он имеется перед `div data-game..` ? только через `prev` или `parent` ?

Comment: @steam.apk2 да - `prev\parent`, либо делать цикл по детям, на строке `const one...`, записывать их в массив(со значениями рядышком, например содержит `cs go`, то `.containTag: true`), потом еще одним отбирать(муторно, но добавляет больше мобильности-handling)

Comment: @steam.apk2 удалятор) Я уже думал, что что-то не так, яж комментарий оставил, что там не детей нужно счёлкать, а сам объедок, удачи // noreply

Comment: Да я потому и удалил, что как обычно..сначала спросишь, а потом моментально решение находится..вот ))